# Mailboxer: modifying how inbox renders - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a gem called [mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer) to allow users to send messages between each other.

In my controller:

```
def mailbox
    @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
end
```

In my view I have:

```
 <%= render mailbox.inbox %>
```

Which renders each conversation subject under a bullet list with a link to trash the conversation. How do I style this or modify how it renders? I can't seem to find the code anywhere that let's me modify how this renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mailbox.inbox` is just an array of conversation objects. The magic here comes from the way that Rails automatically renders a partial for each object in a collection when an array is passed to `render`. You can modify how the collection is rendered by creating your own partial that does whatever you want to do with that array of conversations. This describes it further:

https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app/issues/2

And this part of the Rails guide describes this behavior (might help when you are figuring out how to customize - see section 3.4.5):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render